# How can I make my xcode project automatically select the correct Xcode version when I double click on it?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have multiple versions of XCode installed on my MAC.  When I install a new version of the SDK, I noticed that I can't no longer double-click on the project file for the newer version of XCode to launch the project.  I have to constantly do a right-click and then select the newer Xcode version. (multiple versions now show up when I do a right click). I thought maybe once I right-click selected the newer Xcode app once, it would remember, but it does not. Is there a way to make it so that my project will ALWAYS launch with the newest XCode when I double-click..or must I constantly do a right-click and select the right Xcode version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a right click on your .xcodeproj file. Then select the "Open With" option.

Then select "Other" and navigate to the path the the specific version of Xcode you want to be selected automatically for this project.  You will need to navigate to the correct xcode.app file.  To help you find the right file, note that when you do a default install of Xcode, it gets put into the Macintosh HD->Developer->Applications folder.  However, if you have installed multiple versions of Xcode, navigate to the specific version you have installed and then select the appropriate Xcode.app file.  Make sure you select "Always Open With" in the window you are using to select the app.

Once you do this, you can finally double click on the project and the correct Xcode version will now launch.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on your project and choose **Get Info**, then where it says **Open With**, choose the correct version of Xcode you want to open it. This may not be the official way, but it will work as expected. Also, doing it this way, and clicking on the **Change All...** button will change all of your Xcode projects to open with the one you selected.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to have to old version on your MAC still?

Comment: If you have big projects that were built with older versions, it's always a good idea to keep them around in case you have problems building with the new version.